# Pip installing wrong version on win7,

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, package

I have a package that I am trying to install via `pip install allen-bradley-toolkit`. The package is failing with the following reason.

[image]

The problem seems to related to the fact that pip is trying to install `1.0a1.post0` instead of the latest release version `2.0.0`.  Does anyone have any ideas on what to do about this.  Perhaps there is something wrong in my deployment script.  You can view the [Github](https://github.com/cmseaton42/Allen-Bradley-Toolkit) Library here to see how I am deploying to PyPi.

There is an issue opened on the GitHub Tracker [#2](https://github.com/cmseaton42/Allen-Bradley-Toolkit/issues/2) that you can also reference for more info.

NOTE: The package seems to install fine on my win10 machine.  But I am unable to get it to install on a win7 VM.

Ive also tried installing with the following commands:

- `pip install --no-cache-dir allen-bradley-toolkit`
- `pip install allen-bradley-toolkit==2.0.0` -> this ones throws a 'doesnt exist error`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At https://pypi.python.org/pypi/allen-bradley-toolkit/2.0.0 I see that the wheel is only available for Python 3. You're trying to install it with Python 2.7.

To publish a universal wheel (suitable for both Py2 and Py3) you need to set

```
[bdist_wheel]
universal = 1
```

in `setup.cfg` or run

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel --universal
```

Comment: I noticed this also, Im not sure why it is pushing to PyPi that way. Can you take a look at the setup.py file on the GitHub repo and see what might be going wrong?

Comment: found the issue, i needed to add `python-tag = py2` to my setup.cfg file

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd line of the output has a clue to the problem - "Using cached ..."

You can skip the cache using the <strike>`--skip-cache`</strike> `--no-cache-dir` option to `pip install` or request an upgrade using the `-U` option

edit: updated comment with the correct option (although, seems like that wasn't the problem in this specific case).

Comment: `--skip-cache` is not an option. I have tried running `pip install --no-cache-dir allen-bradley-toolkit` as well as `pip install --no-cache-dir allen-bradley-toolkit==2.0.0`